# Changing UIView rotation will change it's frame size. How to keep frame size after rotating?

Tags: swift, uiview, core-graphics

I'm rotating `UIView` by the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` but I have a problem, The rotated `UIView`'s frame size will be changed on rotation.

```
targetView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y , width: 100, height: 100))
targetView.backgroundColor = .red
targetView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.view.addSubview(targetView)

targetView.center = self.view.center

let rotate = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotatedView))
targetView.addGestureRecognizer(rotate)
```

Here is the rotate function:

```
@objc func rotatedView(_ sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
var originalRotation = CGFloat()
if sender.state == .began {
    sender.rotation = lastRotation 
    originalRotation = sender.rotation

    print("TargetView Frame Size: [START ROTATE] ", self.targetView.frame.size)
    print("TargetView Bounse Size: [START ROTATE] ", self.targetView.bounds)

} else if sender.state == .changed {
    let newRotation = sender.rotation + originalRotation
    sender.view?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: newRotation)

    print("TargetView Frame Size: [ROTATETING] ", self.targetView.frame.size)
    print("TargetView Bounse Size: [ROTATING ROTATE] ", self.targetView.bounds)
    }
}
```

Size will be changed:

```
TargetView Frame Size: [START ROTATE]  (100.0, 100.0)
TargetView Frame Size: [ROTATETING]  (110.564206726133, 110.564206726133)
```

How to keep frame size after rotating just like Start Rotating?!

EDIT:

I have these gestures together: Rotate, Resize, Move.

Move is working well, but Rotate is changing size. I can use bounds here but If I resize too, the bounds is not useful anymore.

Comment: Yes, the frame size increases because the frame is the rectangle that includes all of the content and a rotated square is wider and taller than a non-rotated square. The bounds do not change though.  Why is this a problem?

Comment: @vacawama Because I have to save the rotate and zoomed UIView size and position and generate same UIView later. I can use bounds but I want to add zooming feature too and in zooming the bounds will not changed. :-|

Comment: Can you save the `transform` instead.  That and the `view` should be everything you need to recreate it later.

Comment: I have to convert rotation and size to general measures and send theme to server to present it in other devices too (Android, TV, Web,...). The issue is: Rotating will change the frame size. I have to send size too. (post edited)

Comment: What are the specifications on what the other devices need?  It sounds like you need size of original view, rotation angle, and scale.

Comment: That's the exactly what I need. I convert the my `UIView` size, position based on It's superView to range of 0 to 1 and send it to server. for rotation I have to send 0 to 360. I made all methods for conversion already but just that rotate issue not fixed yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the scaled but non-rotated view size.  You can compute that from the `bounds.size` of the view and the `transform`.

**Example**

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 150))

// Scale view by 3X horizontally and by 4X vertically and
// rotate by 45 degrees
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 4).rotated(by: 45.0 / 180.0 * .pi)

let transform = view.transform

// Find the angle, print it in degrees
let angle = atan2(-transform.c, transform.a)
print(angle * 180.0 / .pi) // 44.99999999999999

// Find scaleX and scaleY
let scaleX = transform.a * cos(angle) - transform.c * sin(angle)
let scaleY = transform.d * cos(angle) + transform.b * sin(angle)
print(scaleX) // 3.0
print(scaleY) // 4.0

print(view.frame.size)  // (530.3300858899106, 707.1067811865476)
print(view.bounds.size) // (100.0, 150.0)

let adjustedSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width * scaleX, height: view.bounds.size.height * scaleY)

// print non-rotated but scaled size
print(adjustedSize) // (300.0, 600.0)
```

---

Here it is as a handy extension that will work for views that are scaled, rotated, and translated (moved):

```
extension CGAffineTransform {
    var angle: CGFloat { return atan2(-self.c, self.a) }

    var angleInDegrees: CGFloat { return self.angle * 180 / .pi }

    var scaleX: CGFloat {
        let angle = self.angle
        return self.a * cos(angle) - self.c * sin(angle)
    }

    var scaleY: CGFloat {
        let angle = self.angle
        return self.d * cos(angle) + self.b * sin(angle)
    }
}
```

Now, if you have a UIView:

```
let angle = view.transform.angleInDegrees
let scaleX = view.transform.scaleX
let scaleY = view.transform.scaleY
let adjustedSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width * scaleX, height: view.bounds.size.height * scaleY)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was amazing. I'm totally noob in math. :D