# Getting rotation angle during animation / getting rotation angle from CATransform3D

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

I'm trying to get the angle of rotation of a `UIView` while it is being animated. I figured out that such properties are available / up to date during animation in the `layer.presentation()`. I'm trying to extract from there the angle of rotation, however, the transform property here is actually a `CATransform3D` and not the simple `CGAffineTransform` that I am used to working with. Is there a simple way to get the rotation angle from the `CATransform3D` or a way to convert to `CGAffineTransform`?

**SOME EXAMPLE CODE**

```
let someView = UIView()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    someView.transform = //...
}

// Called by user interaction / timer
func getTransformNow() {
    if let transform = someView.layer.presentation().transform {
        // Need rotation angle here
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use layer's method `.affineTransform()`. It will return the affine transform structure that corresponds to the value in the layer’s transform property. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410882-affinetransform

Comment: Once you have the affineTransform, take a look at the extension I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51809035/1630618) for determining the angle.